# Reading Text file with Linq with 2 patterns

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, linq, text

I need to read a text file like this

```
MyItemName = Description @ MoreInfo
```

Now I need to convert this 3 fields in to a table. using the '=' and '@' as pattern.

Comment: Should there be three columns?

Comment: I want to query the file with linq

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just splitting on `=` and `@` - this returns and `IEnumerable` of an anonymous class with the properties you are interested in:

```
var items = File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
                .Skip(1) //Skip header
                .Where( line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line))
                .Select(line =>
                {
                    var columns = line.Split('=', '@');
                    return new
                    {
                        ItemName = columns[0].Trim(),
                        Description = columns[1].Trim(),
                        MoreInfo = columns[2].Trim()
                    };
                });
```

This approach would require the separator tokens to be used as separators *exclusively* - if they do occur in any of the fields, this will mess up everything and void this approach.

Comment: Your right it does work.. the problem is that the file begins with a header like this: Sample File Text ------------------------------------- that is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks so much that takes care of the header. if I may ask one more question, can I skip a line that is empty? currently a empty line gives the index problem

Comment: @Ezi: edited in again - take a look at the standard Linq query operators, it's easy to pick up and you can compose your query as you like it.

Comment: thanks so much. I use linq to sql a lot. but not linq to text file.

Comment: @BrokenGlass let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1742/discussion-between-ezi-and-brokenglass)

Answer (score 1):

if you really want to use linq for it...
It doesn't look very nice and it doesn't create a table, but you get the point:

```
from line in File.ReadAllLines(filename)
let eqPos = line.IndexOf('=')
let atPos = line.IndexOf('@')
select new { 
    Name = line.Substring(0, eqPos).Trim(), 
    Desc = line.Substring(eqPos + 1, atPos - (eqPos + 1)).Trim(), 
    Info = line.Substring(atPos + 1).Trim()
}
```